# What kind of connector is this? Slow to no flow

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, valve, plumbing-fixture, shutoff

[image]

What kind of connector is this?
I had to disassemble as there was no flow or almost no flow in a faucet. It actually was completely shutting flow off when I opened valve completely, and otherwise dripping slowly. Notice the central white piece that was blocking the flow.

It’s a 1/2” x 3/8” OD

Comment: It looks almost like a back flow preventer/check valve.  Just wondering if it was installed backwards, that end should be the outlet end.  Is there any arrows on it?

Comment: The valve is quarter turn ball valve. The second insert (white tube) is a mystery, unless you tell us what was connected there

Comment: Just a regular under sink - faucet connector to a copper pipe

Comment: There is a part missing, the one that was inserted in the sharkbite valve, someone massacred it

Comment: I wonder if this is a "special purpose valve" associated with a hot water recirculation loop. It's definitely not a normal shutoff valve, which would look like that but without the cone sticking out of it.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the conical thing at the bottom of the picture is actually attached?

Comment: What does the text say?

Comment: @FreeMan there is no text

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate nope, it's not attached, but the black rubber thing is almost exactly inside diameter of the white pipe

Comment: @Ecnerwal nope it was on cold water line.

Comment: There appears to be _something_ written on the valve. We can only see a few letters `ASSE` something...

Comment: The valve itself is a standard push-on (Sharkbite or similar brand) supply stop.  You say the conical thing with the rod isn't attached.  Is it possible that that piece has fallen out of something else and ended up lodged in the end of that stub? (perhaps another valve on that pipe that came apart internally)

Comment: Yes it appears to be a standard push-to-connect Sharkbite or something similar, with the exception of the white "valve" inside of one end as shown. @ChrisO interesting, could be..it's a mystery for me. I also think that somebody who installed it took it from Lowes or HD and it was an open box and somebody was playing with assembling this with a valve, and then left it in the store, while a plumber didn't notice that and installed as is. I don't think we will know truth by now, I threw this away. I thought there was an obvious explanation for this, but it doesn't look like to be the case.Thanks